# How to remove price value in select option in opencart?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, opencart

I am new to **OpenCart** e-commerce. I want to create a **calculator** for every product. In select box option I want to remove price for the option value but I do not know how to do that. I am using select box's **onChange** event to calculate the product price. In that **onChange** function I am getting the option value using `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`. Javascript function:

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function assign_values(values,sel_vals,id_text,id_select) {
    var mystr       = sel_vals;
    alert(mystr);
    var mystr2      = mystr.split("_");
    var mystr1      = mystr2[1];
    alert(mystr1);
    //var operator1     = mystr1.slice(mystr.lastIndexOf("("),mystr.lastIndexOf("."));
    //var operator1     = operator[1];
    //alert(operator1);

    var myarr       = mystr1.split("$");
    var symbol_s    = myarr[0];
    alert(symbol_s);
    //var symbol_a      = symbol_s.split("(");
    //var symbol        = symbol_a[1];
    //alert(symbol); 
    var split_value = myarr[1];
    alert(split_value);
    var final_value =split_value.split(".");
    var Final_price =final_value[0];
    var original_price_element=document.getElementById('original_price');
    alert(original_price_element);
    var original_prices=document.getElementById('original_price').value;
    alert(original_prices);
    var calculated_price_element=document.getElementById('calculated_price');

    if(isNumber(Final_price)) {
        if(symbol =='+') {
        var total_amount=parseInt(original_prices)+parseInt(Final_price);
        calculated_price_element.innerHTML=total_amount;
        document.getElementById('original_price').value=total_amount;
        } else if(symbol =='-') {
        var total_amount=parseInt(original_prices)-parseInt(Final_price);
        calculated_price_element.innerHTML=total_amount;
        document.getElementById('original_price').value=total_amount;
        }
        //alert('test');
    }
}
```

This function does not work perfectly... I want to calculate the price at product detail page and cart page...How to solve it? Please provide me with solution...

Comment: If you want to remove price, just hide it via css - display:none property

Comment: Hi @SumitBijvani....thank u for ur responsive comment....I already worked it...<span style="display:none;">(+$19.00)<span>...but it will shown in that  select box also..How to solve it...

Comment: did you find any solution for this?